# Make android layout child wider than parent?

Tags: android, layout, cardview

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My output is 
[image]
I want to green view to match the whole screen parent width.
Is this possible?
I want to use the card view as a parent, because it will have elevation.

Comment: Just remove this two line from your parent view....
    `android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"`

Comment: @GowthamanM the ideea is to have the margin on the parent, and not have on the child

Comment: well think logically how  it will happen..child will perform based on parent attributes..

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```